# Having issues while importing whole sccs file into a wrapped selector

Tags: css, sass

I was looking for an easy way to prefix a style sheet and sass works just great. I don't need any building tool, just vs code sass extension, and press watch.

What I did was, renamed the css to scss and then imported it inside the main style nesting in the selector I want, like:

```
#wrapper {
  @import 'style1';
  @import 'style2';
}
```

The issue comes when one of the files has @font-face, they also get prefixed and that is a problem. I checked the issue tracker and apparently this is the correct behavior.
https://github.com/sass/sass/issues/2442

Given that. I am looking for a way to import only the @font-face rules to the root instead of the #wrapper selector.

Is this possible without having to change the content of 'style1' or 'style2' ?

Comment: Solution: don't have `@font-face` "in" anything. Have it be its own file, and explicitly load _that_ file in your index.html with its own dedicated `<link>`. Don't put it in any bundle, or styled component, etc. Either you need those fonts loaded (and since it's 2020, from woff2/woff only, no eot/svg/ttf/otf silliness and _definitely_ no `local()`) for your page to work, or you don't.

Comment: I just want to prefix an existing stylesheet that I should not modify. 

If I have to go into the file and separate it, kinda defeats the purpose.

Comment: if you haven't already, why haven't you already? Those `@font-face` rules should not be inside any other file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to get around this problem with node sass magic importer.

But again you need node scripting and terminal, but can be mitigated with a bundler which kinda is not what I want but at least I can sort of prebuilt it and still use a watcher.

But given the hasle to set this up for such a simple thing I would just go to the style sheet and copy the font-faces to the root of the main file anyways.

If anyone knows a solution with sass only please reply.